# Forest Plot in R - Error in textHeight TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r, plot

Relatively new to R, but I am trying to make a forest plot in R. Here is my code:

```
forestplot(tabletext, 
           #graph.pos = 3,
           knee,new_page = TRUE,
           is.summary=c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,7),TRUE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,11), TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE,6), TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE,4), TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
           clip=c(-3,1.5), 
           xlog=FALSE, 
           col=fpColors(box="black",line="black", summary="black"),
           graphwidth = unit(100,'mm'),
           lwd.zero = (2),
           vertices= TRUE)
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
Error in if (any(textHeight * (nr + 0.5) * 1.5 < info)) info <- textHeight *  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I can't find where it is reference textHeight from, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Solved: The problem apparently had something to do with a small plot box available to fit the graph. I changed it and added this line:

'library(lattice)'
'trellis.device(device = "windows", height = 25, width = 40, color = TRUE)'

This fixed everything.

Comment: Really, the package should return a more informative error message.  Something like "Plot size exceeds device size.  Minimum [x by y] required." would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This could be marked as solved since the author gives one solution within a comment. The plotting device can become too small for the `forestplot()` which can be solved e.g. by:

```
library(lattice)
trellis.device(device="windows", height = 25, width = 40, color=TRUE)
```

Another option without changing the device would be to simply try to reduce the font size of the labels:

```
forestplot::forestplot(tabletext,
       txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex=.25)),
       ...
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you have a Windows machine. If you are on a MacOS or Linux, you need something like:

```
library(lattice)
trellis.device(device = "X11", height = 25, width = 40, color = TRUE)
```

Comment: Not all Linux distributions still use X11.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run `forestplot` within an RMarkdown document to create a large plot with a lot of rows.  Setting `fig.height` and `fig.width` in the chunk options to a large-ish number fixed the problem for me.